# VBA Loop through rows but fails to exclude previous row contents

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following Loop which dispatches email for every used row in the worksheet starting from the second row.

The loop itself works and it dispatches email for every used row starting from the second row.

However, my loop fails to exclude the previous row contents and accumulate them in the each of the next rows' emails. I suspect it is to do with my cell referencing. Would be great if you can help with this :).

```
 Sub TestEmail1()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim aOutlook As Object
  Dim aEmail As Object
  Dim rngeAddresses As Range, rngeCell As Range, strRecipients As String
  Dim ccAddresses As Range, ccCell As Range, ccRecipients As String
  Dim rngeSubject As Range, SubjectCell As Range, SubjectContent As Variant
  Dim rngeBody As Range, bodyCell As Range, bodyContent As Variant
  Dim Table1 As Range
  Dim i As Integer

  Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  LRow = rng.Rows.Count
    For i = 2 To LRow
      Set Table1 = Worksheets(1).Range("K1:R1")
      Set Table2 = Worksheets(2).Range("K" & i & ":" & "R" & i)
      Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
      Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)

      'set sheet to find address for e-mails as I have several people to
      'mail to

      Set rngeAddresses = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i)
        For Each rngeCell In rngeAddresses.Cells
        strRecipients = strRecipients & ";" & rngeCell.Value
        Next

     Set ccAddresses = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i)
       For Each ccCell In ccAddresses.Cells
       ccRecipients = ccRecipients & ";" & ccCell.Value
       Next

     Set rngeSubject = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i)
       For Each SubjectCell In rngeSubject.Cells
       SubjectContent = SubjectContent & SubjectCell.Value
      Next

     Set rngeBody = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i)
      For Each bodyCell In rngeBody.Cells
       bodyContent = bodyContent & bodyCell.Value
      Next

     'set Importance
     'aEmail.Importance = 2

      'Set Subject
       aEmail.Subject = rngeSubject
     'Set Body for mail
    'aEmail.Body = bodyContent
    aEmail.HTMLBody = bodyContent & "<br><br><br>" & RangetoHTML_    (Table1)            
    aEmail.To = strRecipients
    aEmail.CC = ccRecipients
    aEmail.Send

   Next i

  Exit Sub

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are accumulating longer and longer strings in SubjectContent, bodyContent and the other similar variables. Each time you pass through the For i = 2 to lRow loop you add the value of the specified cell in the current row to the associated `Content` variable.

For some reason you've also got an inner loop for each email area, e.g, `For Each bodyCell in rgneBody.Cells`. If I'm reading your code correctly none of those loops are needed.

So, taking into account the above, I would change:

```
Set rngeBody = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i)
  For Each bodyCell In rngeBody.Cells
  bodyContent = bodyContent & bodyCell.Value
Next
```

to:

```
bodyContent = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i)
```

You can use the intermediate `rngeBody` variable if you think it's more readable, but it's not necesssary.

Repeat the above for your other email area variables.